# Display those employees whose salary is less than his manger but more than the salary of any other manager using ORACLE SQL query

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, oracle10g, informatica-powercenter

Display those employees whose salary is less than his manager but more than the salary of any other manager using ORACLE SQL query

Comment: We need to know your data structure to answer this! What tables do you have, what relevant fields are in which table, how are they linked?

Comment: using self join 1) empno,ename,esalry.mgr   empno =100,ename=A,esal=1000,mgr=101      2) empno=101,ename=B,esal=2000,mgr = 102 3)empno = 102,ename =c,esal = 3000,mgr =104 etc . i could complete only half query which gives employees having salary greater than thier own manager eg.SELECT DISTINCT E1.LAST_NAME ,E1.SALARY,E2.LAST_NAME,E2.SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES E1,EMPLOYEES E2 
WHERE E1.MANAGER_ID = E2.EMPLOYEE_ID
AND E1.SALARY > E2.SALARY .   but could not get 2nd part how to do more than the salary of any other manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH mgr_salaries ( empno, ename, esal, mgr, mgr_salary ) AS (
  SELECT empno,
         ename,
         salary,
         mgr,
         PRIOR salary
  FROM   Employees
  START WITH mgr IS NULL
  CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = mgr
)
SELECT *
FROM   mgr_salaries
WHERE  salary < mgr_salary
AND    NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   mgr_salaries x
         WHERE  x.mgr <> m.mgr
         AND    x.mgr_salary > m.salary
       );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really help full answer